# How to add isSerializible parameter to redux store settings

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have next store config

```
const store = createStore(pReducer, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
))
```

I use redux persist and have common problem when I set true in store instead true I get false, so I need add isSerializible param to redux config. In redux toolkit we can set it like

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: myCustomApiService,
      },
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

but how add this param in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `configureStore` from Redux Toolkit instead of `createStore` in your next setup. It will work just as well.